# Android - globally know when app goes into background / user quits

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I know for an activity you can override onStart on onStop methods to know when an activity starts / exits. The issue I'm running into is I want to keep a session open from when a user opens the app until it enters the background / user exits and tying into onStop (for end session) for each activity isn't giving the the results I want, it ends the session every new activity. So I was wondering what are my options for knowing when a user puts the app in the background or exits.

One thing I thought of is keeping track of onStart and onStop (or any two combinations in the activity life cycle) so I know if I have a onStop without a onStart right before the app is exiting. This seems very hacky, not sure if its the right place to start.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please use application class to manage your status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Application` class and use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` to build the logic.

Using for example these two callbacks:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    mBackground = false;
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    mBackground = true;
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)

Comment: This worked for me, I needed up overwriting the onStart and onStop methods so I can keep track of how many activities there are.